# Bootstrap 3 Puzzle Simplified

Tags: html, panel, rows, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is a true Bootstrap 3 puzzle that I am struggling with. Take a look at this code and see if you can solve this puzzle. What I am trying to do is make the center (yellow) section twice as tall (200px) for content purposes and keep the rest of the squares in the same positions and the same height they are now (100px). It must stay responsive.

here is the code I am working with -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
    .blue {
        height: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
        border: white solid 5px;
        color: white;
    }
    .green {
        height: 100px;
        background-color: green;
        border: white solid 5px;
        color: white;
    }
    .yellow {
        height: 100px;
        background-color: yellow;
        border: white solid 5px;
        color: black;
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2 green">green</div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 yellow">yellow</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 green">green</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 green">green</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-8 green">green</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
  ================================================== -->
  <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    div{
        height:40px;
        background-color: rgba(50,50,100,.2);
        border: solid white 5px;
    }
    .white{
        background-color: white;
    }
    .tall{
        height: 80px;
    }
    .row{
        background-color: transparent;
    }
</style>
<div class="container white">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 tall"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 tall white">BOO YA!</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 tall"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 white"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks but that is not what I was having trouble with. The issue is that the center section is (to use your example) 160px tall and on each side of it are 2 divs that are 80px tall each. I cannot get that to work. I can get three of them to line up fine but one is always out of place. What you have is all of that row is 80px tall. Thats no problem. Thanks again, but no cigar :-)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can come up with is have a table visible for tablets/desktops (hidden-xs) and your code visible for phones (visible-xs).
Theres the issue of duplicating content but you could handle that with something like knockout.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
        .blue {
            height: 100px;
            background-color: blue;
            border: white solid 5px;
            color: white;
        }

        .green {
            height: 100px;
            background-color: green;
            border: white solid 5px;
            color: white;
        }

        .yellow {
            height: 100px;
            background-color: yellow;
            border: white solid 5px;
            color: black;
        }

        .tbl {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: separate;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container visible-xs">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2 green">green</div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 yellow">yellow</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 green">green</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container hidden-xs">
        <div class="row">
            <table class="tbl">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="tb-row">
                        <td class="col-sm-2 blue">Blue</td>
                        <td class="col-sm-2 blue">Blue</td>
                        <td class="col-sm-2 blue">Blue</td>
                        <td class="col-sm-2 blue">Blue</td>
                        <td class="col-sm-2 blue">Blue</td>
                        <td class="col-sm-2 blue">Blue</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="tb-row">
                        <td class="col-sm-2 green">Green</td>
                        <td class="col-sm-8 yellow" colspan="4" rowspan="2">Yellow</td>
                        <td class="col-sm-2 green">Green</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="tb-row">
                        <td class="col-sm-2 green">Green</td>
                        <td class="col-sm-2 green">Green</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="tb-row">
                        <td class="col-sm-2 blue">Blue</td>
                        <td class="col-sm-2 blue">Blue</td>
                        <td class="col-sm-2 blue">Blue</td>
                        <td class="col-sm-2 blue">Blue</td>
                        <td class="col-sm-2 blue">Blue</td>
                        <td class="col-sm-2 blue">Blue</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping your left and right div pairs inside a column (strip borders and padding) and making them full width...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css">
  .blue {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: white solid 5px;
    color: white;
  }
  .green {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    border: white solid 5px;
    color: white;
  }
  .yellow {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: white solid 5px;
    color: black;
  }
  .noborder { border: 0; }
  .nopadding { padding: 0; }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 green noborder nopadding">
     <div class="col-sm-12 green">green L1</div>
     <div class="col-sm-12 green">green L2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 yellow">yellow</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 green noborder nopadding">
     <div class="col-sm-12 green">green R1</div>
     <div class="col-sm-12 green">green R2</div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
  ================================================== -->
  <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, this works very well! I'm not sure how exactly but it does work. A little concerned about the open divs, but other than that, nice job! BC

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping all the rows in in "col-sm-12 yellow" class...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
    .blue {
        height: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
        border: white solid 5px;
        color: white;
    }
    .green {
        height: 100px;
        background-color: green;
        border: white solid 5px;
        color: white;
    }
    .yellow {
        background-color: yellow;
        border: white solid 5px;
        color: black;
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-12 yellow">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-2 green">green</div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-8 green">green</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-2 green">green</div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-8 green">green</div>
          </div>
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 blue">blue</div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
  ================================================== -->
  <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```